# Why exactly are self hosted websites deemed that dangerous?

Tags: network, webserver, web-hosting

Up to now I'm using a raspberry pi as a local server for trying out things or hosting my own little projects (beginner level), but I want to make it publicly available (most likely only for people I know, e.g. using self signed certificates). 
I know that you can never be 100% secure. *All I ask is a fair chance*.


I wonder why the opinions on self hosted webservers are that controversial. There are endless amounts of tutorials which claim to set up the server relatively safe, but on the other hand, especially in forums like this (obviously specialized in security), all you read is that it's extremely risky and disadvised.

I followed all of the obvious safety-mechanisms:

- deactivating all unnecessary services
- choosing secure passwords for multiple users (and deleting the default ones)
- running apache on a non-sudo user with almost zero privileges
- using SSH Keys
- adjusting the read/write privileges on all relevant files
- using iptables to block everything except 3 non-default ports for ssh, http and https
- keeping everything up-to-date
- fail2ban

Planned, if I don't discard the whole idea after this post:

- preemtively blocking all IPs not from my country
- using a separate wireless network, like a guestnetwork, for the pi

My questions boil down to: 
**What else would you recommend to secure the server?**


and (disregarding DoS,evading access-control and using the compromised pi for illegal activity)

**How would an attack look like, especially on the other devices in the local network if the only differences are the forwarded ports for http and https to the pi?**

Comment: Do you mean "dangerous to the local network"? What danger are you talking about?

Comment: You have covered most topics. The remaining topics are vulnerabilities within the web server and SSH server (zero day exploits). Review _hardening_ Apache and OpenSSH (or your choice of servers). The guest network is a good idea, physical servers need a DMZ to mitigate LAN attacks. Running another router with port forwarding would also be viable. NAT is **not** your friend in this scenario. Finally, if you can afford the resources configure remote logging, possibly with rsyslog.

Comment: I consider your question as too broad since you essentially ask multiple mostly independent questions: 1. Why is self-hosting a site considered dangerous (especially for beginners)? 2. What can be done additionally to secure the server?  3. How do attacks look like?  - I would say that asking about 2+3 explains essentially 1. - i.e. not knowing how attacks look like (3) makes it hard to properly protect yourself (2) and that's why it is better to let professionals manage such servers (1).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I understand where you are coming from but you just admitted that 2.+3. explain 1. and therefore they are not really independent. And all the questions combine each other to: "If these well known security mechanisms, which everybody knows and advises, are implemented, why is there still so much distrust?" Also, how are you supposed to become professional if you never try it?

Comment: @Nesuma: not the answer to 2+3 explains 1 but the fact that you need to ask about 2+3 in the first place. The questions are still mostly independent.

Comment: I recommend beginners start by self hosting, on their own metal.  Self hosting on the cloud is not as safe. If you lose data on the cloud it is really lost. Your issues are the same, but you own the local network and can physically pull the plug on a compromised box. You have access to option ROM and hardware components. Your issues equally apply, with the fear of neglect generally being your driver. How well do you trust a paid support provider anyway? The fact that you are here says you are better off than most.